# Xcode compiler plugins & native build settings for platforms

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, clang

I'm coming up against a problem in the creation of an Xcode compiler plugin that appears to be the result of a problem in the way compile lines are generated by Xcode and how some of these options are overridden by the platform SDK.

Upon creating a custom compiler plugin that functions perfectly when building applications for MacOSX. I noticed a problem when building applications for iPhoneOS. The SDK continually complains about an invalid value in the min-iphoneos-version variable, the reason being that this isn't set on the compile command-line. Looking at the iPhoneOS platform SDK for Xcode5 you notice that the setting is defined in the `'Native Build System.xcspec'` file `(Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhone*.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/)`. Essentially, from what I can gather, this file is consulted and the -mmin-macosx-version flag is overwritten with this command-line option which results in a valid build for Apple compilers. However, create your own compiler plugin and problem ensue since your new compiler will *not* be matched by any of the 'Compiler' definitions in the '`Native Build System.xcspec'` file.

I can only think of a couple of solutions to this,

- rewrite/patch the `'Native Build System.xcspec`' file upon installation, resulting in an horrendous solution requiring making unsupportable patches to Apple's build system.
- another technique that allows a custom compiler plugin to define options specific for a platform SDK via some matching technique,
- if a new .xcspec file is added to a Plugin in the PrivatePlugIns directory as a Resource, do all of these files get parsed upon build-time? if so then it may be possible to add these settings to a file such as,

  ```
  Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/iPhoneSimulator Build System Support.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/MyPlugin.xcspec
  ```

Has anyone else come up against this 'road-block' (ahem, design problem)?